# sencha touch List Component render event is not effect

Tags: sencha-touch

Below is my source code.

```
this.list = new Ext({
 ....
)}

this.list.on('render', function(){ ... }, this);
```

The render event of list component is not effect on application

There is no error message in browser(chrome).

why does not effect?

Comment: You need to be a lot more specific. Can you post a demo or a js fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need a list render event? If you want to show any item, use "itemTpl" config. If you need to work on itemtap/doubletap etc, you can anyway use those events which provides you a list instance along with taped record.

Comment: I want to show progress animation on page during receiving the jason data from server by AJAX. Then, which event is needed to this situation?

Comment: add loadingText:'Loading..' in list config and the animation will come automatically.